Stored Procedure Creation Returns Success but No Procedure Exists
I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server, and while the command executes with a "Commands completed successfully" message, the procedure does not actually appear in the database (under stored procedures)
Here’s the SQL code I ran:
USE [SA_PSP_OFEK];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    PRINT 'This is a test stored procedure.';
END
GO


I refreshed the Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio.
What could be causing this issue?

How are you determining it's not there? If you run the query again does it run successfully? Are you checking the wrong database? Did you not refresh the object explorer?

It works fine for me: db<>fiddle

@ThomA if I run the query again it fails on the first time with "There is already an object named 'test' in the database." but if I run one more time it again run successfully with "Commands completed successfully" refreshing the explorer didn't help I just don't see the procedure I add...

@ThomA if i run your select i can see the procedure listed.
but after closing the query window and run again nothing listed...

Then something else is DROPing the object. That's going to be impossible for us to debug for you
